# How to regex match and replace to katex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, katex

**updated**

```js
function test() {
  var text = "3 sqrt(11) %i - 1 1 + 3 sqrt(11) %i 50 50 3 sqrt(11) %i - 1 1 + 3 sqrt(11) %i [x = - -----------------, x = -----------------] 50 50 3 sqrt(11) %i - 1 1 + 3 sqrt(11) %i 50 50i";
  var alter = text.replace("()","{}").replace(/(\d+)?([sqrt])/g,"\\");//i need a answer 3\\sqrt{11}
  alert(alter);
  katex.render(alter, document.getElementById('demo'));
  }

test();
```

```html
<script src="https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/bower_components/katex/dist/katex.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/bower_components/katex/dist/katex.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I have string  `3sqrt(11)`in  match and replace using regex .Because i was get the output via katex formet.
I was tried with below script:

```js
function test() {
  var text = "3sqrt(11)";
  var alter = text.replace("()","{}").replace(/(\d+)?([sqrt])/g,"\\");//i need a answer 3\\sqrt{11}
  alert(alter);
  katex.render(alter, document.getElementById('demo'));
  }

test();
```

```html
<script src="https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/bower_components/katex/dist/katex.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/bower_components/katex/dist/katex.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single `.replace` call using captured groups:

```js
function test() {
  var text = "3 sqrt(11) %i - 1 1 + 3 sqrt(11) %i 50 50 3 sqrt(11) %i - 1 1 + 3 sqrt(11) %i [x = - -----------------, x = -----------------] 50 50 3 sqrt(11) %i - 1 1 + 3 sqrt(11) %i 50 50i";
  
  var alter  = text.replace(/(\d+)\s*(sqrt)\((\d+)\)/g, "$1\\\\$2{$3}")

  console.log(alter);
}

test();
```

Here in 1st group we are matching & capturing `sqrt`. In 2nd group we are matching `(` followed by some number followed by `)`.

Then in replacement we add `\\` before 1st group backreference i.e. `$1` and wrap `$2` around `{` and `}`.

Comment: please explain it.

Comment: `3 sqrt(11) %i - 1 1 + 3 sqrt(11) %i 50 50 3 sqrt(11) %i - 1 1 + 3 sqrt(11) %i [x = - -----------------, x = -----------------] 50 50 3 sqrt(11) %i - 1 1 + 3 sqrt(11) %i 50 50`in full string solve.

Comment: please check your updated its error are declared and how to replace the x=.......

Comment: you give the updated question i substitute but error producted.so please helpme

Comment: not getting  kadex output please apply with your script edit my question you will find out my error.

Comment: See updated answer with demo included. It generates `3\\sqrt{11} %i - 1 1 + 3\\sqrt{11} %i 50 50 3\\sqrt{11} %i - 1 1 + 3\\sqrt{11} %i [x = - -----------------, x = -----------------] 50 50 3\\sqrt{11} %i - 1 1 + 3\\sqrt{11} %i 50 50i` as output. What is your expected output?

Comment: please one help me your updated demo its ok but that output how to print in katex format.so give me katex to print the var text="....xxx" value.

Comment: I don't know `katex`, what is your expected katext output?

Comment: its input `3\\sqrt{11} %i - 1 1 + 3\\sqrt{11} %i 50 50 3\\sqrt{11} %i - 1 1 + 3\\sqrt{11} %i [x = - -----------------, x = -----------------] 50 50 3\\sqrt{11} %i - 1 1 + 3\\sqrt{11} %i 50 50i` that text are replace and print the katex `3\\sqrt{11}....`are output are wanted.please help me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Instead of the output you're getting from above input what is your expected output?

Comment: i want to katex format output for your give the `console.log (alter)`output to shown in katex format.

Comment: please help me.

Comment: As I commented above I don't know `katex`. You need to tell me what is **expected string output** so that I can tweak if needed.